# PNG to Opengl usage issues

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm trying to collate several native PNG images into Opengl & I'm having some roadblocks. I'm already using a Cximage library, so would prefer to stick to this if I can help it.

3 related issues;

1. PNGs are showing as black & white in OpenGL. The image isn't the issue as Other image types work but I'd rather not convert unless it's easy & doesn't require disk saving or another library.
2. PNG having black background which are suppose to be transparent.
3. OpenGL view/Orientation issue. Image is skewed in OpenGL ie not orientated properly. The PNGs contain isometric views, which I'm trying to display.

**Sample** of code I am currently using;

*And Yes I realise I'm using depreciated Opengl. I need to due to legacy code I am working with.

```
int MyScene::LoadTexture
{
    m_pImgCol = new CxImage((BYTE *)pdatabuffer, (DWORD)filesize, CXIMAGE_FORMAT_PNG);

    DWORD iDest(0), iSrc(0);
    DWORD dwSize = m_pImgCol->GetWidth()*m_pImgCol->GetHeight();
    BYTE  *pSrc = m_pImgCol->GetBits();
    BYTE  *pDest = new BYTE[dwSize * 4];
    BYTE  *pSrcA = m_pImgAlpha ? m_pImgAlpha->GetBits() : NULL;
    BYTE  alpha;

    for (DWORD iX = 0; iX<dwSize; iX++)
    {
        alpha = 255;
        if (pSrcA)
            alpha = pSrcA[iX];
        else
        {
            if (pSrc[iSrc] == 0 && pSrc[iSrc + 1] == 0 && pSrc[iSrc + 2] == 0)
                alpha = 0;
        }
        pDest[iDest++] = pSrc[iSrc++];
        pDest[iDest++] = pSrc[iSrc++];
        pDest[iDest++] = pSrc[iSrc++];
        pDest[iDest++] = alpha;
    }

    GLuint iTexture=0;
    glGenTextures(1, &iTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, m_pImgCol->GetWidth(), m_pImgCol->GetHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pDest);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}


int MyScene::DrawGLScene()
{
    CRect rWnd;
    GetClientRect(&rWnd);

    glViewport(0,0,rWnd.Width(),rWnd.Height()); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();                       
    glOrtho(-20 * m_Zoom, 20 * m_Zoom, -15 * m_Zoom, 25 * m_Zoom, 20000, -20000);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glTranslatef(0, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(m_rx, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   
    glRotatef(m_rz, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  
    glRotatef(m_ry, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    DrawScene();

    SwapBuffers(m_pView->m_hDC);
    return TRUE;
}


int MyScene::DrawScene
{
    float dL = -8;
    float dR = 8;
    float dT = -8;
    float dB = 8;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(dL, dT, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(dL, dB, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(dR, dB, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex3f(dR, dT, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glEnd();
}
```

If necessary I can provide more code, but this is as basic as I can break it down to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Found http://ysflight.in.coocan.jp/programming/pngdecoder/pngdecodere.html & modified it to read existing buffer. Minimal fuss, no disk saving or library.
2. got PNG transparency working by adding;

   ```
   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   ```
3. Imaging tearing; seems I had following in wrong order;

   ```
   glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
   glVertex3f(dL, dT, 0);
   ```

Comment: 2. PNG transparency; 
it seems for some the image itself was a source of issue, and thus have had to adjust the rgba data manually and add/change transparency for the PNG image itself, as follows; 
       if (rgba[index] != 0 && rgba[index + 1] != 0 && rgba[index+ 2] != 0)
       rgba[index + 3] = 0xff;